# Do unity remote work with android device without switching project platform to andriod

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity-remote

I am trying from last several hours to play unity remote device on Samsung glaxy device but unable to do it. I have confirm all the steps:

1. opened the Editor Settings in Unity (menu: Edit > Project Settings >
   Editor) and select the device to use from the Unity Remote section.

but i didn't switch my platform to android(I don't want it ever cause i only want to test touch which will run on windows touch screen). So which thing i am missing to play remote? is this mandatory to switch platform on Android before using unity remote.

Comment: Have you enable development setting in Android device ??

Comment: development mode where?

Comment: In Android device Setting.

Comment: You should restart unity editor and test again.

Comment: development mode is not found in developer options while i have enabled usb debugging option. i also restart several times

Comment: Settings > About Phone > Build Number 7 times. and you will see it.

Comment: oh man i have done this that why developer option is showing to me. Now is this option available in developer option or it separate?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not required to switch platform to Android.

[Unity Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unity3d.genericremote&hl=en) on Android Device works even if your Platform on Unity Editor is *PC, Mac & Standalone*. But, sometimes it is confusing. Here are some steps you shouldn't miss.

1. First make sure you have Android SDK installed on your PC. Here's [the docs describing that](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html).
2. On Unity, Go to **Edit > Project Settings > Editor** and under **Unity Remote** make sure Device is selected to **Any Android Device**, and Joystick Source is **Remote**.
3. Now, you'll have to restart the Unity Editor, but **wait**, before you start Unity, connect your Android Device to your machine and start Unity Remote App on the Android Device. Make sure USB Debugging is enabled on your Device.
4. Now, after your device is connected to PC and Unity Remote App is running on the Android Device, start Unity Editor and open your project.
5. Click Play and you should see the app playing on your android device too.

Sometimes, you might need to redo it when it does not work on first run.